# Selecting an element with Id having colons in Sizzle/jQuery

Tags: jquery, escaping, sizzle

I have an HTML which has some elements having ids with colons. For example,

```
<div id="i:have:colons">Get my selector!!</div>
<my:another:test> This time with tag names </my:another:test>
```

I want to select these elements using jQuery. Here are my few attempts and [Jsbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/lejili/1/edit?html,js,console)

```
function escape(id) {
  return id.replace( /(:|\.|\[|\])/g, '\\$1');
}

var id = "i:have:colons";

// Does not work
console.log($('#' + id).length);

// Works
console.log($("#i\\:have\\:colons").length);

var escapedId = escape(id);

// Q1. Why answer shows only 1 backslash while I used 2 in regex
console.log(escapedId); //'i\:have\:colons'

// Works
console.log($('#' + escapedId).length);

// Q2. Does not work while escapedId === 'i\:have\:colons'. How and why ?
console.log($('#' + 'i\:have\:colons').length);
```

### Edit After T.J Answer

```
var tag = 'my:another:test';

console.log('Testing tag name now----');

console.log($(tag).length);

var tag2 = tag.replace(/[:]/g, '\\\\:');

// Does not work with tagnames but this works with Id
console.log($(tag2).length);

var tag3 = tag.replace(/[:]/g, '\\:');

// Q3. Why does this work with tagnames but not with ids ?
console.log($(tag3).length);
```

My Question is in the comments in JS code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> // Q1. Why answer shows only 1 backslash while I used 2 in regex

Because the string you used as a substitute only had **one** backslash in it, because backslashes are special in string literals. To get an actual backslash into the selector, you need `\\` in the string literal. But your `escape` function is correct, because you only *want* one in the actual regex.

> // Q2. Does not work while `escapedId === 'i\:have\:colons'`. How and why ?
>
> `console.log($('#' + 'i\:have\:colons').length);`

Much the same reason, there are no backslashes in the selector. `\:` in a string literal is just `:`. You need to escape the backslashes:

```
console.log($('#' + 'i\\:have\\:colons').length);
```

Options for selecting these elements:

1. Escape the `id` value correctly, using your `escape` function.
2. Use `getElementById`:

   ```
    $(document.getElementById("i:have:colons"))
   ```
3. Use an attribute selector:

   ```
    $('[id="i:have:colons"]')
   ```

   But that will be slower (although the odds of it mattering are low), as jQuery won't optimize it into a `getElementById` call.

Comment: I am happy to accept the answer but just wondering why the same logic is not working with tag names. Checkout http://jsbin.com/lejili/2/edit?html,js,console

Comment: @blunderboy: Actually, part of my answer was wrong (now fixed), your `escape` function was fine; my answer to your actual Q1 was correct, but then I went off on a tangent that was incorrect. So the answer to your Q3 is: It *does* work with both IDs and tag names: http://jsbin.com/cukib/1/edit?html,js,console (Although note that HTML tag names are not supposed to have colons in them: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-tag-name)